# Display the selected rows from one to gridview to another when the checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, gridview

The gridview values is coming from excel sheet when the checkbox is checked i want those rows to be displayed into another gridview when the button is clicked

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("Name of the Chemical "), new DataColumn("Grade"), new DataColumn("Quantity"), new DataColumn("Price in"), new DataColumn("Total") });
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelect = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);
            if (chkSelect.Checked)
            {
                string name = row.Cells[1].Text;
                string grade = row.Cells[2].Text;


               // int quantity = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[3].FindControl("Quantity") as TextBox));
                //Decimal price = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
                //Decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4]);
                //Decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[5]);
               // Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text)
                //string country = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(name, grade);
            }
        }
    }
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    //gvSelected.DataSource = dt;
    //gvSelected.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Good luck, let us know if you get any questions or get stuck

Comment: i am not able to display the quantity, price and total fields

Comment: i am getting error in the line Decimal price= Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);

Comment: I need to know what data the gridview contain.

Comment: Name of the chemical, Grade, Quantity, Price in and Total these are the fields present in excel sheet and getting displayed in the first gridview..

Comment: now i am getting all the values i had given it as a datafield but its a textbox.. problem is solved